# Processing a string using as.yearqtr

Tags: r, date

Good morning,

Let's assume I have the following variable in R:

```
r <- c("Q412", "Q113", "Q213","Q313")
```

To transform this into yearqtr, I would have thought that this would do the trick:

```
as.yearqtr(r, format = "Q%q%y")
```

But, all I get is:

```
"NA QNA" "NA QNA" "NA QNA" "NA QNA"
```

What's the best way to fix this? After some experimentation I also noticed:

```
> as.yearqtr(x = "14 Q2", format = "%y Q%q")
[1] "2014 Q2"
> as.yearqtr(x = "14Q2", format = "%yQ%q")
[1] "2014 Q2"
> as.yearqtr(x = "Q2 14", format = "Q%q %y")
[1] "2014 Q2"
> as.yearqtr(x = "Q214", format = "Q%q%y")
[1] "NA QNA"
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated,

Philipp

---- Update:

```
> sessionInfo()

R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] gridExtra_0.9.1  ggplot2_0.9.3.1  lattice_0.20-27  xts_0.9-7       
 [5] Haver_1.2        forecast_5.2     timeDate_3010.98 dyn_0.2-9       
 [9] lubridate_1.3.3  markdown_0.6.4   gplots_2.12.1    reshape_0.8.4   
[13] plyr_1.8.1       googleVis_0.4.7  zoo_1.7-11       shiny_0.9.1     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bitops_1.0-6              caTools_1.16             
 [3] colorspace_1.2-4          dichromat_2.0-0          
 [5] digest_0.6.4              fracdiff_1.4-2           
 [7] gdata_2.13.2              gtable_0.1.2             
 [9] gtools_3.3.1              httpuv_1.2.3             
[11] KernSmooth_2.23-10        labeling_0.2             
[13] MASS_7.3-29               memoise_0.1              
[15] munsell_0.4.2             nnet_7.3-7               
[17] parallel_3.0.3            proto_0.3-10             
[19] quadprog_1.5-5            RColorBrewer_1.0-5       
[21] Rcpp_0.11.1               RcppArmadillo_0.4.100.2.1
[23] reshape2_1.2.2            RJSONIO_1.0-3            
[25] scales_0.2.3              stringr_0.6.2            
[27] tools_3.0.3               tseries_0.10-32          
[29] xtable_1.7-3
```

Comment: As a work around, you could add a space to each string at 2 characters, but I'd say this looks like a bug.  I haven't dug into the zoo source to see the implementation though...

Comment: The error happens in the call to `as.yearmon` where it converts `%q` to `%m` and back.  Since `%m` can take 1 or 2 digit months, it cannot determine what to do with the string: is `Q123` `2013-01` or is it `2003-12`.  Instead of inserting a space, you can zero pad the quarter `Q0413` and will get the expected results.

Comment: It allows quarters to be specified as one or two digits, eg. 01, and as a consequence gets confused about whether the second digit is part of the quarter or the year even though in principle it could tell by looking at what the digit is.   It does assume that quarters can't be more than 2 digits long so this would work: `as.yearqtr(sub("Q", 0, r), "%q%y")` .

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

If anyone else encounters this issue, here's a one-line fix:

```
Date.Fix <- as.yearqtr(paste(substr(r,1,2), " 20", substr(r, 3,4), sep=""), format = "Q%q %Y")
```

Answer (score 1):

`gsub` comes in super handy if you would like to have such a regular string manipulation:

```
library('zoo')
r <- c("Q412", "Q113", "Q213","Q313")
as.yearqtr(
  gsub('(Q.)(.*)', '\\1-\\2', r), # Place a hyphen between the Q(char), & the rest of the string
  format='Q%q-%y')
```

Comment: Or `as.yearqtr(sub("(..)", "\\1-", r), format = "Q%q-%y")`