# Convert character/string vector to dates

Tags: r, datetime, type-conversion

I am trying to convert quarterly dates to a  "DATE" object in R

my vector is:

```
r <- c("2010-Q4" "2011-Q1" "2011-Q2" "2011-Q3" "2011-Q4" "2012-Q1" "2012-Q2" "2012-Q3" "2012-Q4" "2013-Q1" "2013-Q2" "2013-Q3" "2013-Q4" "2014-Q1" "2014-Q2" "2014-Q3")
```

This is a random date vector

I am trying to apply the solution offered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22965195/processing-a-string-using-as-yearqtr), but unfornaterly the suggested answers does not work, and all I get is `NA`.

Any ideas please?

Comment: You can't convert quarters to DATE objects, unless you want a particular day of the quarter (like the first or the middle).

Comment: Your line for creating `r` is missing a *lot* of commas and doesn't work when pasted into R.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation for `as.yearqtr` and setting the appropriate format string works for me:

```
> as.yearqtr(r,format="%Y-Q%q")
[1] "2010 Q4" "2011 Q1" "2011 Q2" "2011 Q3" "2011 Q4" "2012 Q1"
```

Side-by-side:

```
> data.frame(string=r,q=as.yearqtr(r,format="%Y-Q%q"))
   string       q
1 2010-Q4 2010 Q4
2 2011-Q1 2011 Q1
3 2011-Q2 2011 Q2
4 2011-Q3 2011 Q3
5 2011-Q4 2011 Q4
6 2012-Q1 2012 Q1
```

If you want Date objects based on the first day of the quarter:

```
> as.Date(as.yearqtr(r,format="%Y-Q%q"))
[1] "2010-10-01" "2011-01-01" "2011-04-01" "2011-07-01" "2011-10-01"
[6] "2012-01-01"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your formatting is incorrect. The following seems to work:

```
library('zoo')
r <- c("2010-Q4", "2011-Q1", "2011-Q2")

# The format string encodes: %Y: 4 digit year, then a hyphen, 
# then a capital Q, then %q which refers to the actual quarterly digit.
as.yearqtr(r, format='%Y-Q%q') 
# [1] "2010 Q4" "2011 Q1" "2011 Q2"
```